# How to give explicit size to UIImage inside of a UIStackView with padding?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

### TL;DR

1. How do you add padding *inside* a `UIStackView`, kind of like how we add padding for `SwiftUI` `HStack`s?
2. How do you use a `UIImageView` with explicit height inside of a `UIStackView`?

### Context

I have the following scenario:

A `containerView` that is pinned to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell`. The `containerView` is responsible for showing rounded corners and having a `backgroundColor`.

The `containerView` has a horizontal `stackView` as a subview. The `stackView` has a `UIImageView` and a `Label`.

The `stackView` needs to be padded by 8 px on all sides.

The `imageView` has to be `18 x 18` - *This is what's giving constraint issues in the debugger, and is the constraint that autolayout suggests to break*.

My assumption is that autolayout is saying - "You want the `stackView` to be the height of its content, *plus* 8 px padding, but the `imageView` also has an explicit size - what if there's not enough room to make the `imageView` that size?

### Code

Here's the `iconImageView`:

```
    private let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
        imageView.constrainedSize = CGSize(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
        imageView.image = UIImage(image: image)
        imageView.tintColor = .color
        return imageView
}()
```

Here's the layout code:

```
    private func setupView() {
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        contentView.pinView(containerView, positions: .all, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 4, right: 0))
    
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(iconImageView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(messageLabel)
    
        containerView.addSubview(stackView)
        containerView.pinView(stackView, positions: .all, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8))
}
```

### What I've Tried

- Rearranging the contraints
- Giving the `stackView` an explicit height
- Giving the `stackView` a `constraintGreaterThanOrEqualTo` constraint

Comment: you'll need to explicitly give the cell a height (`heightForCellAt:`), or you can have it be a [self-sizing cell](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells). To add padding within the stack view, you can use the `directionalLayoutMargins` property on the stack. To remove the debugger warning around the image view, you can just add an empty view as an arranged subview of your stack to fill up all the empty space that's not taken.

Answer (score 0):

Set it with auto layout. Set your imageView like this:

```
private let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // set image height
    return imageView
}()
```

now in viewDidLoad (in my example case) set label, stackView and constraints

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    label.text = "My custom text"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [iconImageView, label])
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 10 //your padding
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // same constant that imageView width
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, I haven't overlooked this! I'm going to come back to this and test it out!